# Sending form data with react Router from a Component to another

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple form where the user inserts his info and I want to send his info to another Component that I navigate to with Router Link

**FormulairePlayer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class FormulairePlayer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Age:'',
            Sexe:'Homme',
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
      }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert("L'utilisateur a était soumis " + this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>  
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formAge">
                        <Form.Label>Age</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="number" name="Age" value={this.state.Age} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Age" required="true" />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formSexe">
                        <Form.Label>Sexe</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control name="Sexe" as="select" value={this.state.Sexe} onChange={this.handleChange} >
                            <option selected value="Homme">Homme</option>
                            <option value ="Femme">Femme</option>
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Link to="/StartGame">
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                            Suivant
                    </Button>
                    </Link>
                </Form>

            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it with Router Link or should I use another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<Link />` component to send data as props while you navigate between components.

*Update:*

```
handleSubmitEvent(event) {
  alert("L'utilisateur a était soumis " + this.state.value);
  event.preventDefault();
  return (
  <Redirect
    to={{
      pathname: `/StartGame`,
      state: { age: this.state.age, sex: this.state.sex },
    }}
  />)
}

<Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
  Suivant
</Button>;
```

And you can access this props in your navigated component via `this.props.location.state`. Since you are using a class-based component, you can access it in a lifecycle method and set the state when the component is initially rendered like this for example:

```
componentDidMount(){
console.log(this.props.location.state)
}
```

Comment: How can I retrieve the data inside the new component?

Comment: And you can access this props in your navigated component via `this.props.location.state`

Comment: Any luck there @AnisKaloun?

Comment: Thanks, it worked just now, had a problem with variable names !

Comment: I now have a small problem with my form, my form doesn't check anymore if it's filled or not, it just sends me to the next component? is there a way to fix this? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212161/discussion-between-anis-kaloun-and-ajin-kabeer).